# FCKEditor taking one blank space in chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, fckeditor

[image]

Fckeditor taking one blank space on load in chrome only.In all other browsers it is not taking blank space.

I tried  below code but it just crashes chrome.

```
function FCKeditor_OnComplete(editorInstance) {
editorInstance.Events.AttachEvent( 'OnFocus', FCKeditor_OnFocus ) ;
}

function FCKeditor_OnFocus( editorInstance )
{
    editorInstance.SetHTML("");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below code resolves that issue.

```
function FCKeditor_OnComplete(editorInstance) {


 if( editorInstance.GetHTML() == '&nbsp;' )
   {
      jQuery( editorInstance.EditorDocument.body ).html( '' );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

editor/js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js

editor/js/fckeditorcode_ie.js

FIND `A=E[1]+'&nbsp;'+F[1];`
REPLACE `A=E[1]+''+F[1];`

Comment: How does this solve the problem?  Can you be more complete in your solution?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not speak English (from Russia).
We need to find two files in the folder FСKEDITOR
editor/js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js
editor/js/fckeditorcode_ie.js
and they find the code
`A=E[1]+'&nbsp;'+F[1];`
and replace it with
`A=E[1]+''+F[1];`